# Can't use QFont type property values when extending QML properties?

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2

here is my code

**mytext.cpp**

```
#ifndef MYTEXT_H
#define MYTEXT_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QtQml/qqml.h>
#include <QFont>

class MyText:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QFont font READ font WRITE setFont)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString fontFamily READ fontFamily WRITE setFontFamily)
    Q_PROPERTY(int fontSize READ fontSize WRITE setFontSize)
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    MyText(QObject* object = nullptr);

    QString fontFamily()const{return family;}
    void setFontFamily(const QString& fy){family = fy;}

    int fontSize()const{return ftSz;}
    void setFontSize(int sz){ftSz = sz;}

    QFont font()const{return ft;}
    void setFont(const QFont& f){ft = f;}

private:
    QFont ft;
    QString family = "default family";
    int ftSz = 12;
};
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import MyText 1.0

MyText{
    fontFamily:"asdasdad"
    fontSize:20
    //how to set the value of 'font' property ??
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include "mytext.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    auto *pMytext = qobject_cast<MyText *>(component.create());

    if (pMytext) {
        qWarning() <<"mytext family is = "<< pMytext->fontFamily()
                  <<"fontSize = "<<pMytext->fontSize()
                 <<"font is = "<<pMytext->font();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    qWarning() << component.errors();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

when i runing ,i get output:

> mytext family is =  "asdasdad" fontSize =  20 font is =  QFont(,-1,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0)

so,my question is how could i set the value for the property of 'font'? if no way,how qquicktext work for the element of 'Text'?
and one more question,if i change the type `QFont` to `QFont*`,is there any way to setting in qml file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the font method of Qt Qml type:

```
font: Qt.font({family: "Arial", pixelSize: 20})
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#font-method

Or setting the font's properties individually:

```
font.family: "Arial"
font.pixelSize: 30
```

Note, that the two methods cannot be mixed, so if you set the `font` property you cannot override `font.pixelSize` for eg.

Edited: fixed typo in the font method example

Comment: `font.family: "Arial"font.pixelSize: 30`  is work for me,but `font: Qt.font({family: "Arial"; pixelSize: 20})` not ,After I changed the semicolon to comma it worked(`font: Qt.font({family: "Arial", pixelSize: 20})`). OK,thanks @Andras but one more question,if i changed the type `QFont ` to `QFont *`,is there any way to setting value in qml file?

Comment: Indeed there was a typo, I fixed that.  I don't think the `Q_PROPERTY` with type `QFont *` will work, but your C++ class can store a `QFont *`, you just have to update the setter and getter and make sure it's never a null pointer. I wouldn't do that though, as `QFont` is a value type it doesn't have an identity.