# QML TextEdit font.preferShaping not matches QFont::PreferNoShaping

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qfont

I have QML component with TextEdit:

```
TextEdit {
    ...
    font: settings.myFont
    font.preferShaping: false
```

when load the component I get error `qml Can't create component <path_to_my_qml>: Property has already been assigned a value` pointing to the line `font.preferShaping: false`.

I try to comment the line `font.preferShaping: false` and set the property on the c++ side by:

```
QFont Settings::myFont() const
{
    ...
    font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferNoShaping);    
    return font;
}
```

but then the appearance of the text matches the default value of the `font.preferShaping` property, which is true.

How can I set the `font.preferShaping` property to false without errors?

---

Ultimately, I need to achieve the same display of a text in QML and on c++ side, where the text draws via `updatePaintNode`:

```
QSGNode* Text::updatePaintNode(QSGNode* oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData*)
{
    ...
    painter.setFont(settings.myFont());
    painter.drawText(rect, alignment(), m_textParams.text());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problematic line is the setting of the `font` property which yields undesirable behavior so, your symptoms are actually unsurprising. The solution is you need to deep copy your font properties, e.g. `font.family: settings.myFont.family` and so forth.

Comment: Somewhat similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71362575/cant-use-qfont-type-property-values-when-extending-qml-properties

Comment: the line `font: settings.myFont` is problematic ?

Comment: Yes. My understanding is the `font` property feels like an object, and you assign it feels like it is destroying the underlying object and creating a new one. After that happened, I've noticed unpredictable things happen. So, the recommendation is try not to do that, hence the recommendation to deep copy the properties within.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the property after the onFontChanged signal is emitted:

```
Text {
   id: text
   font: settings.myFont
   onFontChanged: {
       text.font.preferShaping = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't help

Comment: Interesting. If I do it like this I can check preferedShaping and it is set to false...the font has to be diffenrent to the old one. Otherwise the function onFontChanged is not called. Have you checked, if the signal is emitted?

Comment: You could use Component.onCompleted to set the flag. This handler is called in any case.

Comment: it is not possible to use both `font` and `font.preferShaping` properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71362575/cant-use-qfont-type-property-values-when-extending-qml-properties